# Regular Expression to find specific Javascript in source code

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a Regular Expression to tell me if a website is using Google Adsense. Here are two options for the source code

- `src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">`
- `google_ad_client =`

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: plugin? bookmarklet? What if the link is within text, like it is on this page?

Comment: please DON'T use a regexp to find a string in HTML

Comment: In which programming language would you like to execute that regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, regular expressions don't have to look like hieroglyphs. This might be one of them. :)

**1. A simple regex that matches either string:**

```
src="http://pagead2\.googlesyndication\.com/pagead/show_ads\.js"|google_ad_client\s*=
```

**2. A basic php implementation:**

This echoes the matches.

```
$subject='THE INPUT YOU ARE TESTING FOR THESE TWO STRINGS';
preg_match_all('%src="http://pagead2\.googlesyndication\.com/pagead/show_ads\.js"|google_ad_client\s*=%', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) echo $result[0][$i]."<br>";
```

Is this what you are looking for?